# Rails gcal4ruby gem uninitialized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, google-calendar-api, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm trying to create a Ruby on Rails web app that will sync with google calendar. I tried to use omniauth but it didn't work for me.

I found a rails gem that should do the job for me: [gcal4ruby](https://github.com/SeabourneConsulting/GCal4Ruby)
But for now it isn't working.
I use the code:

> @serv = Service.new
>
> @serv.authenticate 'account@gmail.com', 'pass'

and got an error:

> uninitialized constant UsersController::Service

In my gemfile using:

> gem 'gcal4ruby', '0.5.5'

Gem was installed successfully after bundle install.

By trying to use similar gems I got the same error so I suppose that issue is something else.

I tried to use require "gcal4ruby" in my code and got error:

> cannot load such file -- gcal4ruby

I'm using ruby 1.9.3 and rails 4.0.2.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
require 'gcal4ruby'
include GCal4Ruby
```

Which mixes-in the Service class.

Note, that GCal4Ruby uses version 2 of the google calendar api which is deprecated and will not work after November-17th 2014.

Here is a great tutorial on getting a rails app working using omniauth.